# WCF SOAP security negotiation

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Application running under a windows service.  When I have my client try to connect to it I get this error...

> SOAP security negotiation with
> 'http://machinename:8000/WcfService/service' for target
> 'http://machinename:8000/WcfService/service' failed. See inner
> exception for more details.
>
> Inner exception is:   {"Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI)
> authentication failed. The server may not be running in an account
> with identity 'user@domain'. If the server is running in a service
> account (Network Service for example), specify the account's
> ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the
> server. If the server is running in a user account, specify the
> account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for
> the server."}

I set up my endpoint identity like this:

```
EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("user@domain");
```

It seems like the Windows Service is running under an account I am unfamiliar with because this configuration works for a console application.  I have the service log on as Local System.  What account does that use?  How do I set this up so I can have my client connect to the WCF server that is running as a windows service?

Comment: Why don't you run the service under specific domain account? In case of Local System or Network service try to use computerName@domain. Btw. both your client and server must be in the same windows domain.